# Can a bowler bowl a six?

Tags: rules, cricket, scoring

Imagine a very fast bowler. The ball pitches, is missed by the batsman, is missed by the wicket keeper, and flies over the boundary. How much runs/extras?

Imagine a very fast bowler. The ball doesn't pitch, is missed by all, and flies over the boundary. How much runs/extras?

Bonus: Did either ever happen at some reasonable level? (The first might be physically impossible, but the second seems doable.)

Comment: "The 'first' might be physically impossible" ? I think you mean the 'second' one ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it has to come off the bat to be a six. Any ball going over the boundary without hitting the bat is a four. If the ball is a full toss above waist high (at any speed other than slow) it is also a No ball. So in the situation you describe it is either four byes, five wides or four byes and one run penalty for the No ball (five runs altogether).

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia - Wide (cricket)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_%28cricket%29):

> If the wicket-keeper misses the ball and it travels all the way to the boundary, the batting team immediately scores five wides, similarly as if the ball had been hit to the boundary for a four on a no ball. **If a wide ball crosses the boundary without touching the ground, only five wides (not seven) are scored - according to [Law 19.5 (c)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/), a boundary six can only be scored if the ball has touched the bat.**

So in the both conditions the batting team will be awarded **five** runs as extras.

Comment: Thanks. You assume that it must a wide ball. But the Wikipedia article on the [Bye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bye_(cricket)) says roughly the same thing and even mentions my condition 1. So, I guess it's either 5 wides, 5 no-balls, or 4 byes.

Comment: @aufkag - Assume your first imagination is physically possible. Now do you really think the ball which is pitched on legal area (so that the ball is not considered as *wide*) but missed by everyone and can fly over the boundary? So *byes* are really not possible physically. That's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions it: "In the virtually impossible case that a bouncer bounces so high that it flies directly over the boundary without touching the ground, only 4 byes are awarded." I guess "virtually" leaves room for possibility. :)

Comment: @aufkag - I think this can be possible only on [Cricket 07](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_07) :-)

Comment: Wikipedia actually makes things less clear in this case (although it is correct). [Law 19(c)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/) makes no reference to wide deliveries - its wording covers all deliveries: _"a Boundary 6 will be scored if and only if the ball has been struck by the bat and pitches beyond the boundary."_ And with regard to byes - it's perfectly possible that a ball could go for 4 byes without touching the field after pitching. Think Brett Lee + tiny boundary + extremely bouncy pitch!

Comment: To note it is possible to score a six on a no ball if it hits the bat, and as indicated if the keeper misses it its not automatically 5 wides it could be 4 byes.

Comment: @BenWhyall - here the op is **not** talking about the bat touching the ball on no-ball. He is talking about the ball being no-ball and goes directly out of the boundary **without** touching batsman,keeper and/or ground. And I didn't get your second point.